# How to select/set a selected row in picker view as default selected row every time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, datepicker, uipickerview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a picker view

```
[picker selectRow:3 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

when i wrote this code in view did load,

This method is used to set the row 3 as default row in picker.

But i want that the row i have selected is set to be as default for the next time.

what to do? thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
NSUserDefaults *usrDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    [usrDefaults setInteger:row forKey:@"Index"];
}

[pickerView selectRow:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"Index"] inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you save the last pressed row in a variable and you load it next time?

Something like:

```
    int myLastPressed;

   - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

        myLastPressed = row;

    }
```

You can use a variable in your code, or a global one in NSUSerDefaults

And then next time:

```
[picker selectRow:myLastPressed inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is very unprecise. What do you want to do?

`selectRow:inComponent:` is exactly what you have to call, if you want a specific row selected.
If you want to save the selected state for the next appstart, you could save the current selected row (read with `selectedRowInComponent`) in the UserDefaults: `[[NSUserdefault standardUserDefaults] saveInteger: selectedRow forKey @"savedSelectedPickerRowComponent1"]`